# How can I call a possibly-non-existent method, without errors, in one line in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was writing a program that uses javascript and creates inheritance in a way.

If the user types in:

```
x.isSingleLine()
```

and it does not exist, it crashes Javascript.  I was hoping there was a way to do something like:

```
x.isSingleLine() || "Doesnt Exist";
```

to in a way have it do a soft error or some sort of alert.  I didnt want to have to encapsulate the object in a try-catch block.

Is there a way this can be accomplished?

In the statement: *x.isSingleLine() || "Doesnt Exist";* it will crash and not do the OR part, so this is not the answer apparently.

Comment: "it crashes Javascript" - it's more accurate to say that JavaScript throws an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about that?

```
  x.isSingleLine ? x.isSingleLine() : console.log("Doesnt Exist");
```

**Edit:**
As suggested by @FelixKling if there's a chance that `isSingleLine` exists but is not a function you should instead use:

```
(x.isSingleLine && x.isSingleLine instanceof Function) ? x.isSingleLine() : console.log("Doesnt Exist");
```

Comment: This would be the answer if you ask me. Nice and short. But this doesn't catch any failure of the isSingleLine() method itself.

Comment: i dont need it to catch errors in side, just the existance of the function

Comment: Out of curiosity; why use `instance of Function` instead of `typeof x.isSingleLine === "function"` ?

Comment: Personal preference - I dislike code that depends on magic strings.

Answer (score 5):

You need to check if it exists *before* calling it.

```
var result = x.isSingleLine ? x.isSingleLine() : "Doesn't Exist";
```

Comment: It will still throw an error if the value is not a function. Might not be relevant here though.

Comment: @FelixKling: True, you might wanna do `typeof x.isSingleLine === 'function'`, but I'm assuming it's either a function or undefined.

Comment: For just determining if it exists, `x.isSingleLine !== undefined` would work best, regardless of status as function or value. It avoids situations like someone setting `x.isSingleLine = false` or `x.isSingleLine = 0` or `x.isSingleLine = ''`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know from the top of my head, you can use a try-catch block for that:

```
try {
    x.isSingleLine();
} catch (e) {
    // Something happened
    alert("isSingleLine didn't quite work out.");
}
```

Play around with it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/biinjo/HcqXX/)

**Update**
I now noticed that you don't want to encapsulate in a try-catch block. Using a try-catch block though can even handle errors inside the isSingleLine() method as shown in the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/biinjo/HcqXX/1/).

Comment: *" I didnt want to have to encapsulate the object in a try-catch block."*.

Comment: @FelixKling my bad, overlooked that one.

Answer (score 0):

```
(x.isSingleLine || function(){
    console.log("Doesn't Exist");
})()
```